# Using variables in nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have some nested ng-repeat. Something like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="phase in vm.phases track by phase.id">
    <td>{{phase.name}}</td>
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="task in getTasksByPhaseId(phase.id)">
            <td>{{task.name}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</tr>
```

phase.id in the 2nd `ng-repeat` is showing up as undefined. How do I evaluate the variable in the ng-repeat?

Comment: Add some extra information about `JSON `data.

Comment: check if you need `vm` for your function, I think you are using ControllerAs syntax, try: `vm.getTasksByPhaseId(...)`

Comment: No it is in the scope directly. Accessing the function is not an issue, phase.id inside a ng-repeat is not properly going in as a value.

Comment: I also tried assigning phase.id to another variable in outer ng-repeat with ng-init. That also did not work

Comment: If I do `<tr ng-repeat="task in getTasksByPhaseId(1)">` I am able to get the data properly. I am not sure why phase.id variable is not expanding

Answer (score 0):

make sure getTasksByPhaseId function of your controller is accessible here

Comment: It is accessible but is saying phase.id is undefined.